# How to begin with game development using basic concepts?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to learn the basic concepts like collision detection, rendering and others in a general way (keeping the library usage minimum). I believe that once my basic concepts are clear, it would help me in learning different libraries easily, like OpenGL, etc.

I know without libraries it will take long time to build things. I am doing this for learning so I don't care about productivity.

I would love if the solution is using JavaScript (HTML5 Canvas) or C/C++ (DOS mode) since I believe I will have to deal with a bit of low level stuff which would help me in learning. Other solutions are also welcome. I know Java as well.

Note: 2D games are sufficient for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started in game development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223/how-do-i-get-started-in-game-development)

Comment: That is a general question. I want to get started without (or with minimum) libraries.

Comment: +1 for a really good question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question - A decent place to start is

http://www.gameinstitute.com/

They have some pretty fun courses, no time limit and a decent forum. I actually met some good local dev's there and since have done some stuff together.

I'd also look at getting into the yearly Global Game Jam (http://globalgamejam.org/). 
It's a really great experience for novice and professional devs. You can also meet local people.

I mention "local people" cause sometimes its very difficult to do a game on your own - it really helps to have people to collaborate with. Though it brings in problems of its own (schedule conflicts, motivation, etc).

I'd take a look at the following books:

1. [http://www.amazon.com/Ultimate-Guide-Video-Writing-Design/dp/158065066X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1306204693&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/158065066X)
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Game-Design-Workshop-Second-Playcentric/dp/0240809742/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1306204693&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0240809742)
3. [http://www.amazon.com/Masters-Doom-Created-Transformed-Culture/dp/0812972155/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1306204765&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0812972155)
4. [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Game-Example-Mat-Buckland/dp/1556220782/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1306204779&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556220782)
5. [http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1306204798&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135)

This are just a few books on the top of my head that I've enjoyed in my travels.

I'd focus on a language like python that'll get you up and running quickly. Not C++ - I think you lose a lot of productivity on the language it self, templates, smart pointers, vtables, etc. And then you have all the different version of DX, Win32 GDI etc. I think you'll be more productive in a different language. Maybe lua + python?

Also, I'd seriously look into mastering an engine. I wrote my own, and it was a great journey, but we never completed the GAME! We spent 6 months writing the engine, 2 months writing the game and got burnt out. Next time I'd use an engine for sure!

1. Unity3D works on iphone, web, desktop.
2. Torque is another leader, though I didn't find this one as slick as Unity.
3. Cocos2d is a iphone specific framework, based on a python framework. Really slick.

Another option is taking an existing game that allows Mods (HL2, Quake, etc) and build some mods for it. You can probably find tons of forums and groups already doing it and perhaps contribute to an existing project or start your own.

Another really gnalry idea would to be to get the Blue Book

1. [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321498828/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_2?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=032117383X&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=01F2GM7XZD56GCFW0AJT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828)

And don't stop till you understand and have worked through it!!! You'd be a pretty good openGL / C coder by the time you made it through that book (cover to cover). Set aside a few months...heh.

Don't forget - you can always start with paper-prototyping games, you don't have to start building computer games.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should focus on making games that are fun. Yes, you'll understand more as you work with low-level tools. However, you'll understand more about making fun games as you make more games.

1. Make a list of ideas for games.
2. Go down that list and pare things
   down until they can be implemented
   in 16 hours of work or so.
3. Pick one of the ideas, and learn
   new libraries, technologies, et
   cetera as you go. Don't overengineer your game.
4. Let other people play it. Try to
   get honest feedback.
5. Improve your game. Stop when you
   need to start from scratch to
   improve it.
6. Go back to step 3, and try not to
   make the same mistakes :)

Comment: I understand this. But how do I begin?